# Functional issue on <apex:vote>

Tags: visualforce

Issue: VF page getting the wrong votes/points if change the query dynamically

Actually i am trying to display the all ideas with votes in ascending or descending order by title.

Ascending Order: Query has built in constructor, displaying vote and title in proper manner (Working fine)

Descending Order: Query has built in method, will fire when the user click on the button 'DESC'. This should display the ideas vote and title in descending order, but this is not showing in proper manner
Problem: Idea Titles are displaying in Descending order but Votes are displaying in ascending order

Please check the below codes:

## VF page:

```
<apex:page standardController="idea" extensions="ideasample01cls" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" >
    <style>
        .votePanelstyl{
           font-family:calibri;         
        }
        .IdeaListTitle{   
            float: left;  
            font-size: 14px; 
            font-family: 'Calibri'; 
            color: blue;
        } 
    </style>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton reRender="panelid" style="margin-left:300px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:20px" value="Desc" action="{!samplemthod}" />
        <apex:outputPanel id="panelid">
            <apex:repeat value="{!idealistP}" var="ida">                
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20%">
                            <div class="votePanelstyl" >
                                <apex:outputPanel id="votePanel" >                                                    
                                    <apex:vote objectId="{!ida.id}" rerender="IdeaList" /> <br/>                                                                               
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td width="80%">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="IdeaListTitle">                                                          
                                            <apex:outputLink value="{!$Site.prefix}/apex/CPIdeaDetailPage?id={!ida.id}" styleClass="ideahometitl" > {!ida.title} </apex:outputLink>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>                       
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>                               
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:outputPanel>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

## Controller:

```
public with sharing class ideasample01cls {
    public list<idea> idealistP {set;get;}
    public ideasample01cls(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.idealistP = [select id,title,body,NumComments,VoteScore, VoteTotal,Status, CreatorFullPhotoUrl,Creatorname,CreatedDate,(Select CommentBody,CreatedById, CreatedDate From Comments limit 1) from Idea  ORDER BY title ASC];

    }
    public void samplemthod(){
        idealistP = [select id,title,body,NumComments,VoteScore, VoteTotal,Status, CreatorFullPhotoUrl,Creatorname,CreatedDate,(Select CommentBody,CreatedById, CreatedDate From Comments limit 1) from Idea ORDER BY title DESC];
        //return idealist;    
    }
}
```

Screen shorts for more clarity:
[image]

[image]

Please help me to solve this issue or guide me for any work around to solve this

In above two screens, order of votes are same, i want show the related votes for all list of ideas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned.